# WooCommerce: How to change the label name Dimensions?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

WooCommerce has a default attribute in the products data table called dimensions which takes values entered as LxBxH. I would like to change the label name **dimensions** to **packaging dimensions** in the front end as well as if possible in the back end.
What code has to be entered in functions.php in order to achieve the same?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function woo_replace_string($translation, $text, $domain) {

    $search_string = 'Dimensions';
    if (strpos($translation, $search_string) !== false) {

        $translation = str_replace($search_string, 'Packaging Dimensions', $translation);
    }
    return $translation;
}

add_filter('gettext_woocommerce', 'woo_replace_string', 20, 3);
```

Use gettext_{$domain} hook for this. See the doc [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/)

Comment: Its working in the front end!